# How to find the HtmlInputCheckBox of a repeater control in code behind file without using runat ="server" tag

Tags: asp.net

Inside repeater i have a html checkbox , now i want to access this checkbox in code behind file to check whether the checkbox is checked or not. but i dont want to user runat="server" tag , how can i do this my code as above

```
 <input id="cbfdgroup" class="checkitem" type="checkbox" name="fd_cb_group[]" value='<%#Eval("FoodItemsUid") %>'>
```

in code behind file i am trying to access like this

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptMenu.Items)
        {
            if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || ri.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)ri.FindControl("cbfdgroup");

                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

but this is giving error as object referrence is not set to instance of an object.. how should i get this control in code behind file without using runat = "server" tag

Comment: Why don't you want to use runat="server"?

Comment: For what reason is it not possible? presumably if you have control over say the codebehind, you'd have access to the aspx page? or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jeff I'm aware of the logistics between making a control available to server side code, purely trying to ask the OP why they are under the impression that 'It is not possible'

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I thought that was directed at me.  Where does the OP say its not possible?

Comment: i found the solution myself.. just i have given dummy class name to the checkbox .. so that it can be accessable through my jquery code.. so i will get some values after that i used the check box with runat attribute only .. i can check that checked or not in code behind file..thanks for all responding on my problem

Comment: @Jeff Oh sorry, my mistake! I thought the OP was saying it wasn't possible to use runat="server", that will teach me for not reading the names!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe what you are asking is possible. `runat=server` is what makes controls available to the code behind. If you remove that attribute, your code behind is simply not aware of the control in any way.

A little bit more explanation:

The codebehind executes on the *server*. Therefore, any control you want to access in your codebehind must have `runat=server` in order to be available. The two are inseparable.

Comment: the checkbox .. so that it can be accessable through my jquery code.. so i will get some values after that i used the check box with runat attribute only .. i can check that checked or not in code behind file..thanks for all responding on my problem

Comment: adding the runat tag should not prevent your checkbox from working with jquery...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.  To clarify, the `runat="server"` portion is doing just what it says.  It is saying that this control should be made available and accessible to the server.

Code which is in the code-behind is code which is running on/executed by the server.  So logistically, if the control is not made available to the server, the it cannot be manipulated by code (hence when it will not show up in intellisense either.)

Comment: the checkbox .. so that it can be accessable through my jquery code.. so i will get some values after that i used the check box with runat attribute only .. i can check that checked or not in code behind file..thanks for all responding on my problem

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to read the items from repeater

assuming that you are sending a postback to the server (http post)

you can read the selected checkbox by simply:

```
string x = Request["fd_cb_group[]"];
```

it is more than 1 it will separate by comma, just use split the get a list of string of selected values.

the whole thing would be something like that:

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = Request["fd_cb_group[]"];

        string[] allSelectedOnes = x.Split(',');

        foreach(string item in allSelectedOnes)
        {
            //your custom code for the selected checkboxes
        }
    }
```

Comment: the checkbox .. so that it can be accessable through my jquery code.. so i will get some values after that i used the check box with runat attribute only .. i can check that checked or not in code behind file..thanks for all responding on my problem

Comment: Yes, this does technically work. However, it throws away a huge chunk of the functionality asp.net brings to the table. When asp.net came out, one of its greatest benefits was that we no longer had to parse the response object manually.

Comment: SouthShoreAK, the code below helps what Suresh wants to do, and if he is going to use on a postback that already exists, he can still use without impact in his webform application (keeping viewstate, abstracting request,reponse..)  the point is, you can still use both worlds if you use it carefully